# Data frame into list

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to convert my data frame into a list

```
    g<- c( 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4) 
    d<- c (10, 20, 10,10,52,45,45,50,65,58)
    mydata <- data.frame (cbind (g, d), colnames = c("g", "d"))
```

I tried `split()` but it didn't work!

Comment: Did you try as.list() as @juba suggests? It will do what you want w/r/t the question but is that really what you want to do?

Comment: as @cciotti alludes to. Perhaps in this situation, explaining your general objective might help get an answer better suited to your needs

Comment: YES! It works! I tried before but it seems that it wasn't working! 
Thank you guys!